# One sample t-test with variance not assumed to represent the population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, t-test, standard-deviation, inference

Let's say you had a hypothetical study where you believe the sample standard deviation might be different from the population standard deviation. With a Welch's t-Test, you could work around this if it was two-sample. But this would be one-sample. Are you able to still test using the sample variance an estimator for the population and statistically have valid results? Just curious how it would work out. I'm thinking the answer is no, but I wanted to ask.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer worth your sample? How was it sampled?

Comment: It's just a hypothetical t test for the mean.